# Is it possible that when click edittext it will show dialog message?

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, listener

I want to click a edittext and show dialog date so I try

```
mDateDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    mDateDisplay.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        }
    });
```

The dialog will show if mDateDisplay is a button

but I want to use edittext

what should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
mDateDisplay.setClickable(true);
mDateDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `android:onClick` attribute in the XML to point to a click-handling function in your Activity subclass.

(These days, of course, when pretty much everyone uses the compatibility libraries, you would probably want to create and show a dialog fragment rather than calling `showDialog()`, but the idea is the same.)

Comment: mDateDisplay.setClickable(true); because of this

Comment: Actually, it probably didn't work because I had left in `if (hasFocus)`, left over from pasting your original code. I updated my code. How is calling `setClickable` causing it to fail?

Comment: @MarioFraiß - Can you provide any details?

Comment: Problem solved, by clean rewriting the part of the code. Thanks to @TedHopp

Answer (score 49):

You can use OnClickListener event to handle the dialog box but after disabling the `android:focusableInTouchMode` of EditText in the xml file like this. 
eg - `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`.

Because when the EditText is first touched it calls the focus event and on second touch it call the click event so you have to disable the focus event first.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to more material about why the first touch will fire the focus event and the second touch will fire the click event?  I've been looking for a blog post to explain this.  How I would understand the pattern is that if focusableInTouchMode and clickable are turned on, both events would fire on a user touching a given view.

Comment: Because Focus and Click are two different events. Focus happens when the element receives focus this might be via Next/Back buttons on keyboard or another method. Click is when someone clicks (touches) the element. This solution stops the field from being focusable and therefore editable as it will never have focus. Click event still fires because it's been touched (regardless of the fact that it can't receive focus).

Comment: i have done same but it's not working,
my case is i want to display dialog on edittext click but when i open dialog on that click first keyboard show then dialog open.

Answer (score 5):

For the Same thing i have used :

```
 sel_date.setClickable(true);
 sel_date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DEFAULTDATESELECTOR_ID);
        }
    });
```

And for setting Selected Date as EditText's Value :

```
private DateSlider.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DateSlider.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DateSlider view, Calendar selectedDate) {
                // update the dateText view with the corresponding date
                sel_date.setText(String.format("%te-%tB-%tY", selectedDate, selectedDate, selectedDate).trim());
            }
    };
```

I have edited the code from Custom Date Picker in Android : http://blog.codeus.net/dateslider-1-0-an-alternative-datepicker-for-android/

You can replace Button with EditText and do the same as above code.

The keyboard seems to pop up when the `EditText` gains focus. To prevent this, set focusable to false:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:focusable="false"
    ... />
```

**Edited**

Check The Following code :

```
public class Main extends Activity {
EditText et1,et2;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID1 = 1;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;

private int mYear1;
private int mMonth1;
private int mDay1;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    et1.setText("month/year");
    et2.setText("month/year");
    et1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            return false;
        }
    });

    et2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID1);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                mDay);

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID1:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener1, mYear1, mMonth1,
                mDay1);
    }
    return null;
}

// updates the date in the TextView

private void updateDisplay() {
    et1.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mYear));
}
private void updateDisplay1() {

    et2.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mMonth1 + 1).append("-").append(mYear1));
}
// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();
    }
};

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year1, int monthOfYear1,
            int dayOfMonth1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mYear1 = year1;
        mMonth1 = monthOfYear1;
        mDay1 = dayOfMonth1;
        updateDisplay1();
    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem. To be simple, in order to solve that, I used the follow code:

```
editText.setClickable(true);
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // showDialog
    }
});
```

In XML:

```
<EditText
     ...
     android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
 />
```

So, the user couldn't edit the EditText, only click it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect code that will give you the output you desired:

```
public class TextView_Calendar extends Activity {
EditText et1,et2;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    et1.setText("month/year");
    et1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}

// updates the date in the TextView

private void updateDisplay() {
    et1.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mDay).append("-").append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mYear));
}

// the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();
    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it with an `onFocusChangeListener` the following way:

```
mCompleteByEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.completion);
        mCompleteByEditText
                .setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (hasFocus) {
                            DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                                    "timePicker");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The `hasFocus` variable controls whether the current `EditText` has the focus or not.